# Frobenius method solution of this nasty 2nd order Linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

I've tried but can't get the solution of this ode by Frobenius method.

$(x^2)y''-6y=0$

I tried with $y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a_k \cdot x^{(k+r)})$  where $a_k$ is coefficient. 
I **can't find the recurrence relation**.
If any one finds the recurrence relation, that'll do it.

Comment: Try setting $z=x^2y$, so that $z'=2xy+x^2y'$ and $z''=2y+4xy'+x^2y''$.

Comment: My university test paper says to solve it by the method of frobenius. 

Comment: One doesn't preclude the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Frobenius, the relation between coefficients is

$$x^2k(k-1)a_kx^{k-2}-6a_k=0,$$
i.e.
$$a_k=0\lor k(k-1)=6,$$ hence the only nonzero terms are

$$a_3x^3+a_{-2}x^{-2}.$$

Comment: Is there something missing, in the first line?

Comment: If you want to do the answer, sir, plz do it with akx^(k+r)

Comment: @mobifz96: nonsense.

Comment: I meant use a solution of this form, not strictly frobenius but tha's what Calcutta University wants us to solve in $y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a_k \cdot x^{(k+r)})$

Comment: @mobifz96: this transformation is trivial, so up to you.